# Do "popular revolts" usually occur with the support of the ruling dictatorship's army?

Tags: history

[CGP Grey's *Rules for Rulers* video](https://youtu.be/rStL7niR7gs) outlines a theory of the social and political forces that govern the rulers of a nation, regardless of that nation's structure of government. In summary, he states that the job of a ruler is mostly to appease those who are capable of actually running the nation, such as the military leaders, the tax collectors, and the law enforcement. Any ruler who fails to appease their so-called "keys" is bound to be replaced.

In [one section of the video](https://youtu.be/rStL7niR7gs?t=14m13s), Grey argues that these rules tend to govern the outcome of popular revolutions in dictatorships. To quote the relevant bits:

> Now understand, the romantic image of the people storming the gates and overthrowing their dictator is mostly a fantasy. If you run a middling dictatorship, the people only storm the palace when the army *lets them* to remove you, because you lost control over your keys and are being replaced.
>
> This is why after "popular revolts" in middling dictatorships, the new ruler is often the same as the old, if not worse.
>
> The people didn't replace the king, the court replaced the king using the people's protest they let happen to do it.

Certainly there are some popular revolutions that were made easier or made possible due to the cooperation of the then-standing military; but is it true that most revolutions are decided by whether or not the current army chooses to let the revolutionaries win, as Grey seems to be stating?

Comment: The video is mostly based on [The Dictator's Handbook](https://www.amazon.com/Dictators-Handbook-Behavior-Almost-Politics/dp/1610391845), so the claim is probably taken from there.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good claim for skeptics as the topic is too complex. What is "usually" and "most"? Is it enough if we name one counter example? 10? 100? Cite a different theory of revolutions? This might be a better fit at politics or history.

Comment: What level of evidence or expertise do you require in an answer? This is basically a fully expressed thesis in any Stratfor analysis (see their coverage of Arab Spring up to and including events in Egypt); do you consider their analysis authoritative?

Comment: In my reading of history, yes, the army was involved in every successful revolt. The American Revolution and similar events stand out as colonial revolts. The homelands were under no threat.

Comment: This is probably going to get a better answer on the History site.